# findViewById always return null using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, findviewbyid

I am trying to update some views that place in a ViewPager in some fragment, 
and every time I am using findViewById I am getting null back.
I tried various of solutions that I find in here (stack overflow) and nothing help.

here is all the code :

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

MainActivity.java:

```
PageManager _pageManager;
ViewPager _viewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    _pageManager = new PageManager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    _viewPager.setAdapter(_pageManager);
    _imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.PictureBox);
```

PageManager.java

```
public class PageManager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    final int NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 3;

    public PageManager(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new CountdownPage();
            case 1:
                return new VideosPage();
            case 2:
                return new SeasonSummary();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
    }
}
```

CountdownPage.java

```
public class CountdownPage extends Fragment {
    int resId=0;
    ImageView _imageView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container==null)
            ShowMessage.GetInstance(null).ShowMessage("error","container");

       return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.countdown_page,container,false);
    }


}
```

countdown_page.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@color/Black"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/countdownLayout"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
        style="@style/HeaderStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Countdown"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/CountdownHeader"
/>

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:id="@+id/PictureBox"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="testF"
/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/counterTextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to solve this for hours 
Thanks a lot,
Or Yaacov

Comment: Can we see stacktrace?

Comment: You have to use findViewById for image view in fragment like: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.countdown_page,container,false);

_imageView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.PictureBox);

Comment: so i can i just find the image? i get now what i did but i still cannot think on a solution

Comment: You can get position and do whatever you wanna do.

Comment: can you show me how to do that please? i am kind of new in Android (i know it's shocking lol)

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageView(id is PictureBox) is in the 'countdown_page' layout xml not 'activity_main' layout xml ,So you should not get ImageView through findViewbyId(int) in 'onCreate()' method in Activity, The ImageView is belong to CountdownPage fragment.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem with `getActivity().findViewById`. Try `getView().findViewById` instead